# WCF e.Result null

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, windows-phone-8

I am calling a WCF service but the result is coming back as null. However when I run the service in the browser I can see JSON being returned no problem.

Code:

```
var webClient = new WebClient();
var uri = new Uri("http://myWebsite.com/MobileService.svc/MyMethod?brandId=brands/1");
webClient.OpenReadCompleted += webClient_OpenReadCompleted;
webClient.OpenReadAsync(uri);
```

And within the webClient_OpenreadCompleted event:

```
ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<SightingType>));
List<SightingType> sightingTypes = ser.ReadObject(e.Result) as List<SightingType>;
```

But for some reason, sightingTypes comes out to be null. Also, when I hover over e.Result whilst debugging, I can see this error:

> ReadTimeout = 'e.Result.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type
>   'System.InvalidOperationException'

Does anyone have any ideas why I can't get the data back?

Comment: Have you tested the URI with a synchronous call?

Comment: And always check `e.Error` first and investigate.

Comment: Just a guess but could it be a problem with the cast to `List<SightingType>`? I would try changing it to this:

`var sightingTypes = ser.ReadObject(e.Result);`

See what you get back and then try some different casting approaches.

Comment: If I use var, I only see the word "object" and I can't step inside it.

Comment: @Henk can you show an example of a Synchronous call please?

Comment: Not on the Phone I think, can you test from a PC ?

Comment: I'm developing the app on Windows Phone 8 on PC. If that's what you're asking.

Comment: When I call the service on the web browser, it works. It returns the JSON perfectly fine.